# Google cloud storage modifies javascript file based on request location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i'm using a Google Cloud Storage regional bucket to host my javascript files. They were working fine worldwide before, but now they are only working when accessed from regional ips (South American), and international IPs get a slightly modified javascript file.

The bucket has no versioning, and the file is hashed, so it was only uploaded once.

The file in question can be accessed by this link: https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/hassets/o/all%2FViewer-7315d2224c220a45ad8e.js?generation=1530894418059107&alt=media

When accessed via South American IPs (where the bucket is located), it will have the following string once: `closeAfter(500)()`

But when accessed elsewhere this string will be modified to: `closeAfter(500)(,"gl")`, thus breaking the script.

Is this supposed to happen? Is there any way for me to fix it?

Comment: It may sound typical, but, could you try accessing in an incognito window? Also, when did this issue started? Have you made any change in GCS? (Bucket configuration and so on). Also, over how many regions do you have this issue?

Comment: Hi, I finally got to fix the issue, it appears that all the web-proxies I was using to test this were adding chars to javascript files for some reason, and my customer that was having the problem in US was because of a unrelated Safari issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! If possible (skipping any private information/steps that may happen, of course), could you post this as an answer? It looked like an interesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, anonymously-readable GCS objects have a caching policy on them, allowing Google and other intermediaries to cache the contents for up to an hour. For anonymous-readable objects, if an object have been overwritten by another object of the same name in the last hour, it's quite likely that users in one region might see the original object but viewers in another region might see the newer one.

I would bet that someone uploaded the first option, downloaded it at least once (loading it into a cache somewhere), then uploaded a second version. This would happen regardless of whether the object had versioning enabled or not.

Note that this would NOT happen if the generation number were present in the URL, which in your link it is. Is this the link you saw the problem with, or were you using something like "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name.js"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This file is uploaded by the server for every application version (and its hash is present in the filename), it is not an user uploaded file. I'm not using generation on the server, but the same problem happens even with the link that has generation number. Also using `gsutil ls -a gs://hassets/all` shows only this generation for the file.

For the record, downlading this link from Brazil right now (with generation) will not have: `closeAfter(500)(,"gl")`

Comment: From North America, following that link, I don't have it either. I'm gonna guess something else is going on. Either there was indeed an earlier upload, or something else is going on, like a web browser extension editing your JavaScript file.